# Empty Response Received on Android POST Request

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

I'm using Volley to perform rest requests on android. When I make a login attempt it fails to give the response and instead returns an empty response.

The server side works fine, I have received the empty response on Android client side.
This is the code I wrote:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", "nifras.personal@gmail.com");
    params.put("password", "123456");

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            urlJsonObj, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    response.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // hide the progress dialog
            hidepDialog();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

Comment: 06-09 13:11:50.239  26850-26992/com.tadhack2015.tuktuk E/Volley﹕ [1671] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://apps.byethost4.com/tuktuk/rest/v1/login

Comment: This error i have received in Logcat

Comment: Have you tried using AdvancedRestClient, if you observe same error there as well?

Comment: I have checked well on postman it's work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct Answer for this question is shown below. In this version of the request, the Post parameters are overriden in the existing getParams() method of Volley. The mistake I did was to not override that method.

```
String url = "http://httpbin.org/post";

StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("form");
                String site = jsonResponse.getString("site"),
                        network = jsonResponse.getString("network");
                System.out.println("Site: "+site+"\nNetwork: "+network);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
) {
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams()
{
    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
    // the POST parameters:
    params.put("site", "code");
    params.put("network", "tutsplus");
    return params;
}
};
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Using Map and Object (I use that for String too) like this:

```
   Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("param1", getParam1());
    jsonParams.put("param2", getParam2());

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(jsonParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
             // ...... you know the rest
```

btw, 400 is usually bad request (if my memory serves me correctly), so I would print the JSON object **before** sending it, and see if it's exactly what server is expecting, you can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to check it too, might be easier (REST client version of Postman in chrome is more comfortable to use).

a **quick and dirty** way to print it:

```
   Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("param1", getParam1());
    jsonParams.put("param2", getParam2());

    Log.d("My JSON Object",(new JSONObject(jsonParams)).toString());
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for solve your problem

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> arrResult  = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
arrSchoolResult.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", ""nifras.personal@gmail.com""));
```

Comment: Its deprecated on Android 5.0

Comment: I am sorry How it to do

Comment: ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("email","nifras.personal@gmail.com");

and pass contentvalues in parameter

Comment: Hi there array list is out dated in the new version of android. That is why it is deprecated.

Comment: Now they using HashMaps any way thanks for your effort.